# Initialize tinymce in angular jS function throws the error second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tinymce

Initialize tinymce editor in angular js init function by passing the textarea id dynamically

HTML Content below.

```
<div ng-app="rootapp" ng-controller="rootcontroller">
    <div id="div1">
        ---first content--------
        <div  ng-controller="editorController" ng-init="getInformation('SettingsDuplicates')">
            <textarea id=" SettingsDuplicates"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
        ---first content--------
        <div  ng-controller="editorController" ng-init="getInformation('new1')">
            <textarea id=" new1"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller.js function

```
$scope.getInformation = function (from) {
    tinymce.editors = [];
    tinymce.init({
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        selector: "textarea#" + from,

        height: 300,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
            'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor'
        ],
        theme: 'modern',
        toolbar1: 'bold italic | underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
            { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
            { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
        ]
    });
    //}
    $scope.screenFrom = from;
    //some service call
}
```

first textarea  converted to editor i.e.fine. but second textarea is not converted to editor it is throwing below issue

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined at g (angular.min.js:58)
```

Comment: Are you using [this library](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce)?

Comment: If you use the unminified version of Angular.js I would expect you to get a more meaningful error message ... have you tried that?  Also - there is a good directive someone wrote to manage the process of having TinyMCE running in Angular while still maintaining databinding:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce

Comment: @Den no i am using other tinymce library not combined with angularjs